# Remove Controller Name from URL

Tags: php, routes, yii

I'm using the PHP **Yii** framework and have stumbled upon an issue:

My URL currently looks like this: `host.com/candidate/default/viewProfile/id/50`

I want the URL to look like this: `host.com/candidate/viewProfile/id/50`

The module is called `candidate`.

Also, the following rule doesn't work: `'/candidate/viewprofile/<id:\w+>' => 'candidate/default/viewprofile',`

Comment: Tried without `/` at start?

Comment: Not sure, but if you set the DefaultController as the defaultController for the candidate module, it should work aswell

Answer (score 0):

First thing can be `/` at the beginning (remove it). Second reason could be that before this rule you can have another rule that also matches your url - in this case just reorder rules and put that one to higher position (I mean nearer to beginning of rules array ;)).

Comment: solution of problem: '/candidate/viewprofile/id/<id:\w+>' => 'candidate/default/viewProfile',